# Trying to Fill a text box with strings from other textboxes in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, fill, autofill

I'm trying to create a simple AD Gui for our HR department to use but I'm hung up on something simple. Our email address format is firstname.lastname@organization.org. I have a text box for first name and for last name and I want the text box for the email to autofill with firstname.lastname@organization.org. I tried

```
string FirstName = txtBoxFirstName.text;
string LastName = txtBoxLastName.text;    
txtBoxEmail.Text = FirstName + "." + LastName + "@organization.org";
```

I also tried not setting them as strings, but that didn't work either. I even tried to have the Email text box fill after the "Last Name" text box loses focus by putting

```
private void txtBoxLastName_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    txtBoxEmail.Text = txtBoxFirstName.text + "." + txtBoxLastName.text + "@organization.org";
}
```

I'm making this in a Windows Form application in Visual Studio Express 2013

Some more Info, I'm very VERY new to this. I've done a lot of searching on the web and nothing seems to be fully fitting my usage case to the point that it's fixed it. In response to a question, here's a more complete code snippet:

```
private void txtBoxLastName_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string FirstName = txtBoxFirstName.Text;
        string LastName = txtBoxLastName.Text;
        txtBoxEmail.Text = FirstName + "." + LastName + "@lgfcu.org";
    }
```

This shows that they're in the txtBoxLastName_Leave.

Comment: So, what exactly do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: Nothing happens. The field does not fill. The strings aren't passed to the txtBoxEmail for whatever reason.

Comment: Are you sure that the functions are firing? Set a breakpoint on the line where txtBoxEmail.Text is assigned and make sure it is hit.

Comment: hopefully, the user will never go back and edit the first name for a typo

Comment: That's a good point Plutonix, I didn't think about that. Since I want them to see the email address populate correctly, what would be a better event to tie it to? Is there a way to have it populate Email text box "realtime"? As in as they're typing in the FirstName or LastName field?

Comment: @Llama11amaduck Sure; in WPF. WinForms its quite a bit harder. You could trap the "TextChanged" event and do your modification on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark and assume that you didn't actually wire the event to the TextBox.  Easiest way to create an event:  Right click on your TextBox, click properties, select the "lightning symbol" toward the top, find the event you desire ("leave" in this case) and double click the column to the right of "Leave".  This will wire the event (look in your designer.cs file for a `+=`) and create the method for you.

Alternatively, if you want to wire the event manually add this code (after `InitializeComponent()`):

```
txtBoxLastName.Leave += txtBoxLastName_Leave;
```

Comment: Which text box would I do that with? If I make it be the Email text box, the firstname.lastname@organization.org populates into Email, but only once I attempt to type in the Email field (I've set it as read only so they can't accidentally modify it). If I set it to call event LastName_Leave when I "Enter" the email field, that works such that when I click in the Email field it populates (correctly) but if I go back and change names, it doesn't correct the email field until I click back in it

Comment: In your example you should do that to the txtBoxLastName *and* txtBoxFirstName.  What you did before was create a method (`txtBoxLastName_Leave`) but the cod e didn't know when to call it.  By "wiring" the event as I described above the code knows to call it upon leaving the TextBox.

Comment: There's also another event called "TextChanged" that could be used instead of "Leave".

Comment: Great, thanks! now I understand how that works. I didn't realize that TextBox_Leave wasn't being called without having some other event call it, silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The textboxes' properties are title-cased, so you need to capitalize the first letters:

```
string FirstName = txtBoxFirstName.Text;
string LastName = txtBoxLastName.Text;
```

or

```
txtBoxEmail.Text = txtBoxFirstName.Text + "." + txtBoxLastName.Text + "@organization.org";
```

Comment: That would cause a compile-time error. It seems unlikely that is what the OP is running into (though not impossible given the lack of detail).

Comment: Tried both .text and .Text and neither one is working out for me. What more detail would you like @BradleyDotNET ?

Comment: @Llama11amaduck Knowing what the current actual behavior (ie. What doesn't work) would be awesome. Also what function the first code sample was in.

Answer (score 0):

@MikeH got it; I had messed up and not been calling my function to populate the Email field. My code was fine,

```
    private void populateEmail(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string FirstName = txtBoxFirstName.Text;
        string LastName = txtBoxLastName.Text;
        txtBoxEmail.Text = FirstName + "." + LastName + "@organization.org";
    }
```

but I had to tie it to an event. I set it such that when the text in FirstName or LastName are edited, it populates the email field which prevents the issue of it not generating correctly if someone goes back into a name field to modify it after clicking in the email box.

Answer (score 0):

We have take string value and string value pass to TextBox

```
String str = "Welcome";
textBox.Text = str;
```